# Nifi ConvertJsonToSQL - Save json object as a db column value

Tags: json, sql-server, apache-nifi

The description of ConvertJsonToSQL says that "If a field maps to a JSON object, that JSON object will be interpreted as Text".
So I'm trying to save a json text "{
"dateEndM" : "2021-12-14 00:00:00.0",
"dateEndY" : "2022-01-11 00:00:00.0"
}" into the db field "InboundData".
Input:

```
{
  "Code" : "27037834",
  "ProductID" : "2",
  "CalculationStatusId" : "1",
  "SystemCode" : "aCRM",
  "InboundData" : {
    "dateEndM" : "2021-12-14 00:00:00.0",
    "dateEndY" : "2022-01-11 00:00:00.0"
  }
}
```

Output sql "INSERT INTO Calculation (Code, ProductId, CalculationStatusId, SystemCode, InboundData) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)" values:

```
sql.args.1.type
-9
sql.args.1.value
27037834
sql.args.2.type
4
sql.args.2.value
2
sql.args.3.type
4
sql.args.3.value
1
sql.args.4.type
-9
sql.args.4.value
aCRM
sql.args.5.type
-9
sql.args.5.value
Empty string set
```

Why sql.args.5.value of InboundData is empty?
How is it possible to save json object as text in db?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an unresolved issue for processor **ConvertJsonToSQL** [NIFI-4359](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-4359)

Possible workoaround with the **EvaluateJsonPath** -> **ConvertJsonToSQL** -> **UpdateAttribute**:

**EvaluateJsonPath**

- `Destination`: `flowfile-attribute`
- `Return Type`: `json`
- `InboundData`: `$.InboundData`

**UpdateAttribute**

- `sql.args.5.value`: `${InboundData}`